# Create file of single instances of account number

Tags: python, string

I have a list of account numbers, separated by line, generated by a log of transactions.

How do I consolidate this list into a file that will have only one occurrence of each account instead of many (where more than one transaction per account has been logged)?

Python is preferred but I can also use C.

Answer (score 5):

```
with open(filename) as fin, open(newfilename, 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(set(fin))
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what your log file looks like, but this should work nicely

in python:

```
file = open('filename.txt', r+)
accountNos = set(file)

file.truncate()
for x in accountNos:
    file.write(x)

file.close()
```

This takes each line out of the file, and stores them in a set.  A set is a data structure that only stores unique elements and removes duplicates.  In the second for loop you write the contents of that set back to the file.

Comment: files are iterable, so you can just pass it to the `set` constructor

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful, had you included a sample log file and your Operating System.

If you are in UNIX environment, it is very simple using awk and sort.

If your log file (called say log.txt) contains the account information as the third word on each line (see log file sample below):

```
LOG WARNING 12345 cancelled ....
LOG WARNING 67482 subscribed ....
```

Please see example below with dollar sign being the command prompt:

```
$ awk '{print $3}' log.txt | sort -u
```

If you are in windows environment, you can download cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/) for Windows, install it and run the above command from the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If order is important, then you can use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    uniques = OrderedDict.fromkeys(fin)
    fout.writelines(uniques)
```